# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in a flask program

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask

[image]

**files used**

1. data.csv - dummy data set i am using
2. main.py - my core flask program

**problem i am facing**

even though pandas is installed in my virtual environment(python3.8 - virtualenv) i am getting *ModuleNotFoundError* for pandas when used in main.py

**additional information**

- There is no error in interactive environment when importing pandas
  within the virtual environment.
- Same error is thrown by webUI by
  flask application.

Comment: ``main.py`` has a shebang for ``/usr/bin/python``, not the venv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main.py` script has the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

pointing to the system interpreter. If you execute `./main.py`, your script is launched with the system interpreter, not the virtual env.

Change the shebang or execute the script with your venv python:

```
$ python main.py
```